# how do I use a variable in its own completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to integrate firebase into my ios app. And one of the features I'm working on involves establishing data within cloud firestore for each user when they register. when they click "register" in my app it creates a new user using firebase authorization and I create a user document in my database within a "user" collection. But I also want to add a subcollection to each user when I create the user which will store their "friends". here is the code where I create the user document when the register button is pressed. I utilize the functions return ability to get a reference to the document I just created. I then want to use that reference to create the subcollection once the document is created, ie when the completion handler is called. But "usersDocRef" isn't given a value until after the completion handler is called apparently. So I can't do it there. How do I access the reference to the document in the completion handler or otherwise use that reference to add a subcollection once the document is done being created? I'm trying to avoid querying to retreive the reference or any more read operations to be efficient, (cause that's a linear relationship with billing cost in firebase land). Any help would be appreciated

```
let userDocRef = self.db.collection(K.FStore.Collections.usersRootCollection).addDocument(data: [K.FStore.Fields.username : email]) { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error registering: \(error)")
                        } else {
                            ///want to use userDocRef here (obviously can't, workarounds?)
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `userDocRef` as an Optional in the previous line:

```
var userDocRef: DocumentReference? = nil
userDocRef = self.db.collection(K.FStore.Collections.usersRootCollection).addDocument...
```

Now the Swift compiler will let you refer to `userDocRef` from inside the completion handler.

Comment: A simple solution and fact I wish I knew hours ago, thank you so much!

Comment: It’s in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_declaration